# PHP / AJAX Application structure

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm working on a PHP / AJAX application and it's quickly becoming unmanageable!

The application is designed to work much like a a desktop application so almost every user action results in an AJAX call.

For every one of these actions I have some jQuery that posts the data to my PHP script and runs a corresponding PHP function that handles the server side actions.

That means in my jQuery file i'll have something like this:

```
$('.delete-project').on('click', function(){
     // Ajax request to http://myapp.co.uk/ajax/delete_project
});

$('.delete-user').on('click', function(){
     // Ajax request to http://myapp.co.uk/ajax/delete_user
});

$('.delete-keyword').on('click', function(){
     // Ajax request to http://myapp.co.uk/ajax/delete_keyword
});
```

I'm sure there is a better way of doing things, but how is it generally done to avoid lots of similar code? The above actions could possible rolled into one 'delete' ajax request which posts the item type and a database ID but a lot of my functions post different data and require different parameters so wouldn't fit so neatly under one jQuery handler.

I've tried finding some resources on how an AJAX application should be put together but all I can find is beginner tutorials on making AJAX requests etc, not how to write a scalable AJAX application.

Just to be clear I know how AJAX works, I'm just trying to find the best way of implementing it in terms of reducing the jQuery and PHP needed where possible.

Are there any good resources that deal with this sort of thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can roll all those into one delete function by using attributes in HTML, for example:

```
$('.delete').on('click', function(){
     var delete = $(this).attr('data-delete');
     // Ajax request to http://myapp.co.uk/ajax/delete_{delete}
});
```

Then your HTML would be something like:

```
<a href="#" class="delete" data-delete="project">Delete</a>
```

[More information on data-attributes](http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/)

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this would help but you could create some functions to reduce your code as it grows. For starters you could prevent duplicating of the ajax call by putting the jQuery .ajax function in a custom wrapper function of your own. For example:

```
function ajaxGet(myUrl, queryString, successCallback, errorCallback) {
    if(queryString) myUrl+= "?" + queryString;
    $.ajax({
         url: myUrl,
         type: "GET",
         data: null,
         success: function (res) {
             if(!successCallback) return;
             else successCallback(res);
         },
         failure: function (res) {
             if(!errorCallback) return;
             else errorCallback(res);
         }
},
```

By creating a wrapper function, you can pass in the needed data without duplicating the $.ajax call code over and over in each of the click functions. You can also create a similar function for an ajax call using post. You could then dynamically build the click functions to further reduce your code:

```
function buildClicks() {
    setupClick([url], [data], [success], [error], [$(elem)]);
    setupClick([url], [data], [success], [error], [$(elem)]);
    setupClick([url], [data], [success], [error], [$(elem)]);
}

//Setup clicks for each button or link

function setupClick(url, data, success, error, elem) {
    elem.click(function () {
        ajaxGet(url, data, success, error);
    });
}
```

In this example I'm assuming your using a "GET" and adding a query string. You could easily adapt this to pass, a JSON formatted object for example, using a custom "POST" function. In that case [data] would be an object not a query string.

Sorry this code isn't the clearest. Let me explain it a little more. The buildClicks function would allow you to setup multiple click events on different elements by passing in the required data. I'm not sure if you are passing any data, but the above functions would allow for it. By dynamically creating the clicks you can avoid duplicating the .click code over and over. Just call the buildClicks function on document ready as such.

```
$(document).ready(function () { buildClicks(); });
```

NOTE: The success and error callbacks are functions that will be executed when your call either completes successfully or errors out. If you do not wish to use these they can be ommitted or null can be passed in. Make sure if you do pass in functions that you leave off the "()" on the end of the function name. Otherwise the functions will be executed prior to the success or failure of the ajax call. For example:

```
ajaxGet("http://testurl.com", null, ajaxSuccess, ajaxFailure);

ajaxSuccess() {

}

ajaxFailure() {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could set an ID attributes to that buttons and a class like `submit-button`.

Then hang a handler on that `$('.submit-button')` while using an ID attribute value to define the URL to call, like that:

```
$('.submit-button').on('click', function(){
    $action = $(this).attr('id'); //lets say the ID's value is 'delete_project'
    $url = 'http://myapp.co.uk/ajax/' + $action;
    // Ajax request to http://myapp.co.uk/ajax/delete_project is done
});
```

Anyway any web application that tends to be like a desktop one is only a bunch of JS and few HTML with some PHP behind... That is always badly maintanable...

I used [extJs][1] once for this, which led to using only jQuery and their modules while no (or just a minimum of) HTML was needed to write...

Answer (score 0):

Not a copy-and-paste-solution, but maybe you find some more ideas how to build a scalable client-server application when looking for how REST APIs are built. I find REST a very good structure to keep a clear server-side API when building such apps, and i'm sure there are tutorials around how to do the corresponding client-part cleanly too.

Answer (score 0):

In my application I do quite a lot of ajax calls too. I found that the easiest way to do things was to create myself a wrapper for all ajax calls such as:

```
var MySite = function()
{

    AjaxWrapper : function(type,url,data,callback,noloading)
    {

        $.ajax({
            type: type,
            url: url,
            data: data,
            success:function(json)
            {

                if(json.status === true)
                {

                    if(typeof callback === 'function')
                    {

                        callback(json);

                    } else {

                        // A generic success handler

                    }

                } else {

                    // An error handler

                }

            }
        });

    };

}();
```

then you'd call it like:

```
MySite.AjaxWrapper("GET", "somehref", {}, function(json)
{

    // json has the result of your json callback
    // you could also make this a separate function
    // or not have it

});
```

this let's you call your ajax on just about anything you want. You could then use something like data attributes, or just the standard href for anything that requires ajax and add an event to all links that pass through this function. Or, if you wanted some to do certain things just make the callback function different for those.

I'm finding this hard to explain, but this is what I've used for a couple of ajax-rich projects and it makes things so much easier!

For an example for your case you could then use something like:

```
$('a[class|="delete"]').on("click", function()
{

    MySite.AjaxWrapper("POST", $(this).attr("href"), {param:number1}, DeleteHandler);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I would do this would be to have a single function for all actions:

```
$('.actions').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var action = $(this).data('action'),
        id = $(this).data('id');

    $.get('/local/handler.php', {
        'action': action,
        'id': id
    }, function () {
        // Callback stuff here
    });

});
```

And HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="actions" data-action="delete-project" data-id="<?=$project_id?>">Delete Project</a>

<a href="#" class="actions" data-action="delete-user" data-id="<?=$user_id?>">Delete User</a>

<a href="#" class="actions" data-action="delete-keyword" data-id="<?=$keyword_id?>">Delete Keywork</a>
```

And the PHP file should have if statements based on the `action` parameter that performs the requested action.

**EDIT:**

- This way your not limited to just delete actions, so you can scale your app in the future.
- Also, If the different actions become a large list (e.g. deletes of many kinds, updates, adding), I would create a separate PHP file for each action and `include` them in one master file. This will allow for easy scaling.